# How to share a controller in multiple directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am stuck with some issue. I have a controller "searchCtrl", It has some scope objects should be used in directives.

If its one directive, it can be used as controller:"searchCtrl". But multiple components need to use searchCtrl which is provided by thrid party( modifying the ctrl is not preferable).

```
file 1;
angular.module('app.core')
    .directive('profilePage', DirectiveFunction1 );
function DirectiveFunction1 (config,service) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/search1.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {}

      }
        return directive;
}

file 2;
angular.module('app.core')
    .directive('contactPage', DirectiveFunction2 );
function DirectiveFunction2 (config,service) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/search2.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {}
      }
        return directive;
}
```

My seachCtrl looks like

```
angular.module('asApp').controller('searchCtrl', ['$scope', 'service', function($scope, AppService, qVarService) {

axisAPI.object()
         .app(service.app())
         .qId('abcd')
         .on('create',function(object) {
             object.paint();
         }).on('paint',function(data){
             $scope.$apply(function(){
                                    $scope.profile = data.profile;
                                    $scope.contacts = data.profile;
              })
         }).create();
```

so 2 components profile and contacts and a common controller. As per my functionality  "searchCtrl" is executing twice and getting response twice as i placed in two directives
instead of that if its used ng-controller in directives html files it will work as same.
Without like above how can i use {{profile}} and {{contacts}} in different directives.

Any one suggest me to do it in betterway.

Comment: `searchCtrl` should be a service instead since they're shared. Controllers are instantiated whenever they're requested. Are you in control of the `searchCtrl`?

Comment: I'm confused, if you're in control of it then you do have a choice right? If you really want `searchCtrl` to be shared then you should make it a service instead.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am not in the control of the searchCtrl.

Comment: OK, I think you just can't share controllers unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If your not in control of the controller can you not copy out the code and place it as service or factory and then reuse it? Or may it change?

Comment: Cool idea and different thoughts. but my bad luck I can't use that because those api calls are controller based. Initialize should happen inside controllers.

Comment: Can i use $watch in directives when scope is updated in controllers